# Jquery delete table duplicates with some twist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

In simple form my html table is such:

```
Article | description | links | price


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        OC 90
        <td>
            ololooo
        </td>       
        <td>
        </td> 
        <td>
            123
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            OC90
        </td>
        <td>
            some other ololo
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="">link</a>
        </td> 
        <td>
            123
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            OC 90
        </td>
        <td>    
            other other oloooloo
        </td>
        <td>
        </td> 
        <td>
            321
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But how can i do, that i delete from my table duplicates, but!!! only if first column (also make it uppercase and delete freespaces when check) and last td (so article and price are same), but main trouble is to left in table such row, which in third column has link's...

After that my table must look:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            OC90
        </td>
        <td>
            some other ololo
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="">link</a>
        </td> 
        <td>
            123
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            OC 90
        </td>
        <td>    
            other other oloooloo
        </td>
        <td>
        </td> 
        <td>
            321
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried something like this:

```
var seen = {};
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        var tr = $(this).clone();
        if(tr.not(':input')){   //tried for input, is not strange)


                tr.find("td:eq(2)").remove(); 
                tr.find("td:eq(3)").remove(); 

               // tr.find("td:eq(2)").remove();
                var txt = tr.text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');;        
                if (seen[txt])
                    $(this).remove();
                else
                    seen[txt] = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

but this doesn't help's me....

also full-version table is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/STrm5/1/

Please help me to delete duplicates from table....

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
var seen = {};
$('#table tr').each(function () {
    var tr = $(this).clone();
    if (tr.not(':input')) {

        tr.find("td:eq(1)").remove();
        tr.find("td:eq(1)").remove();

        var txt = tr.text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
        if (seen[txt]) $(this).remove();
        else seen[txt] = true;
    }
});
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/STrm5/2/)**